# flask-sqlalchemy use of drop_all and create_all for specific tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy (0.8.2), `drop_all()` and `create_all()` both have a `tables` parameter, which can be a list of Table objects to drop or add.

In flask-sqlalchemy (1.0) these methods do not have this parameter.

What is the appropriate way to drop / create a subset of database tables, using flask-alchemy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy's [`create_all()`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.create_all) method will use the Base's metadata to create the table, by calling SQLAlchemy's [`MetaData.create_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/metadata.html?highlight=metadata#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all) method. This method allows for a list of table objects to specify. You will also need to provide it a "bind", which is basically the engine. You can retrieve that using the [engine](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/?#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.engine) property of Flask-SQLAlchemy.

So, you should be able to do...

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class MyTable(db.Model):
    ...

class MyOtherTable(db.Model):
    ...

db.metadata.create_all(db.engine, tables=[
    MyTable.__table__,
    ...
])
```

This assumes that you are using a single database. Otherwise you would need to do a `create_all()` call for each database using [`get_engine()`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.get_engine).