# Flask/SQLAlchemy - error creating models with relationships

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a table `users` with this mysql statement in the shell:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and a table `posts` with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(140) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to use these tables in my Flask app. I created a foreign key connecting `posts` to `users`. It's supposed to be a one-to-many relationship with the user having many posts.

In my python code I have the following models:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Posts', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)


class Posts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(140))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

When I try running my Flask app however, I keep getting the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to
>   initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.
>   Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between
>   parent/child tables on relationship Users.posts - there are no foreign
>   keys linking these tables.

But I created the foreign key connecting `posts` to `users` in the mysql statement. When I take out the line `posts = db.relationship('Posts', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')`, everything works just fine, so the issue lies in that piece of code. What part of my setup is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's wrong with the initial creation of the tables, but i would use sqlalchemy's create_all. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232126/flask-sqlalchemy-use-of-drop-all-and-create-all-for-specific-tables) and in the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables). This way you know any issue is not a matter of different definitions of the initial SQL creation query vs the models' definitions. Stick with SQLAlchemy all the way.

Your model definitions seem OK, except for the backref. I compared it with my models definitions, and my backrefs are always the *table names*. You have 'user' as a backref, which doesn't really appear anywhere else in the code, so i'm assuming that's where things go wrong.

To forcibly define table names add **tablename** to the class definition; e.g.

```
class User(db.model):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    id = db.Column(..
    .. more fields ..
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='Users', lazy='dynamic')
```

I use the convention of the classes in singular, and table names in plural, which makes it easier to see how things are defined, what a backref points to, etc. For example, note that the above relationship points to the *class Post*, while the backref to the *table* Users. Now there's no ambivalence in the definitions.

Comment: awesome, just verify your relationships work as they should .tables can be created with 'strange' relationship definitions without error, but wind up not working as expected.